# Transfer learning from Relation extraction to hate detection, does it make sense?

Tags: keras, neural-network, deep-learning, nlp

so I recently finished my Neural Relation Extraction (RE) model the results were quite notable. I wanted to use transfer learning  with RE being the source task and Hate Detection (HD) is the target task. Does that make sense ?

The thing is in RE I labelled each word in the sentence whether it represents a Entity or Relation or Nothing, so I used categorical cross entropy and treated it a labelling problem, however in HD I will process the whole sentence not each word individually

So do you think using Transfer learning makes sense or the source topic and target topic must be somehow related.

Thank you